# visual studio javascript file editing messes up

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I am new to web-development and try to check out the .net-core 2.1 + react template under visual studio 2017.

The Intellisense works just fine, but when I try to edit any .js-file, the file messes up. When I press enter to add a new line, the line where my cursor was positioned before gets pushed to the right. Also when I paste some code in the file, the code is not formatted. I have to format every line by myself. I am further not able to collapse/expand the nodes like `<Row>foo</Row>`.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I not supposed to edit this files? Or is this how you work with .js-files in VS2017?

Comment: I haven't touched react but if it's using typescript, you might need an extension for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new project with the react-template later. This time the files from the clientapp-folder have the `.ts` or `.tsx` extensions. In these files the problems described in my question are not present.

Maybe the template was updated or something.